# Cleaning Up Generated Code: Refactor or Map?

Tags: refactoring, clean-code

**Context:**

I recently had to deal with a class file generated by XSD.exe. It was 3500 lines long with ridiculously-verbose class / variable names (think `someRidiculouslyLongPrefixThenMaybeOneThingUniqueAtTheEnd` - difficult to compare at a glance with `someRidiculouslyLongPrefixThenMaybeOneOtherThingChanged`) and annotations all over the place. Bottom line is it took me ages to work out what the heck was going on. I read it and thought I would never put my name next to something so... Un-clean.

**Question:**

1) Is it bad practice to mess with generated code (i.e. clean it).

2) Would it be better practice to write a mapper to map the generated classes to my own nice, clean classes (which I could then get to work with, quite happily)?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the comments.

If I was actually going to do anything interesting with it (i.e. if there were domain objects which were anything but transport objects) then I think I'd map them to 'cleaner' classes, which I'd have to do anyway to get any kind of functionality out of them. In this case the classes are effectively DTOs so perhaps it makes sense that the naming matches the corresponding elements. As stated, I don't need to touch it - just to call accessors / mutators before passing the data down to another layer for processing.

For now, I think I'll leave them well alone.

Comment: Why would you even have to look at (let alone change) the generated code? Aside from debugging the code generator, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: They were the class definitions. :|

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but the fact that it's generated means nobody (again, save perhaps the author of the code generator) should have to look at the generated code. Call into it, yes (if the class/method names irk you, can't you write an adapter that isolates the ugliness?), but not look at it.

Comment: had this exact same problem with xsd- went with 2

Comment: Point taken, delnan. I'll deal with the names without feeling too dirty. After all, I didn't author them.

Comment: Think of generated code as sort of like (generated) assembly code.  It doesn't have to be pretty to read because you aren't supposed to read it.  The code that generates the code should be pretty, and the public API should be pretty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The danger with refactoring generated code to clearn and tidy it is that if it is regenerated again by the tool by yourself or another developer then the changes would be lost.

Your team could get yourselves in a position where you would be generating the code in another file and copying it into the cleaned version and refactoring to apply changes which just takes time and resource. (I've been there with the original version of Entity Framework.)

If you cannot live with the names generated, either change the source it generates from or do as you suggest in #2.

Comment: The only time you should edit generated code is if you are SURE you aren't going to have to re-generate it again EVER. If you try to rely on manual edits and have to re-generate, you'll surely lose something along the way.

Comment: The maintenance overhead is definitely the dealbreaker - thanks.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Then three weeks later, the requirements change just a tiiiiiny bit and you have to anyway.  =P

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule, never touch generated code, because doing so means promising that you will never generate it again, or you'll have to redo all the changes you've made. If you want the generated code to look nicer, you have to automate both the code generation and the cleanup; for example, if you generate an XML file somewhere, you might want to run it through `xmlindent` as part of your build process.

For similar reasons, generated code does not belong in source control. You put the data and rules under source control, and let your build script handle the code generation.

Any changes to the generated code have to go through the code generator, that is, if you want the generated code to look different, change the code generator's inputs, the code generator itself, or apply scriptable post-processing. But don't hand-edit.

An exception are 'scaffolding'-style code generators, where you run the generator once to give you a skeleton from which you build further. With those, you'll never run the generator again for the same file, so you just treat the generated file as a regular source file and forget that it comes from a generator.

Comment: Interesting points RE: source control / build process. Hmm. (Sorry I can't +1 yet - had to make a new account :$)

Comment: Note that sometimes generated code is quite expensive to create though. For instance, if it scans the database and you have a large database, you might not want to have to do that everytime you decide to do a new checkout/branch/whatever

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree to @NikolaiDante (+1) answer.

In dotnet/c# you have the concept of "partial classes": The sourcecode for the "class to use" consist of 2 seperate files a generated part and of a manually added/edited part. Your api-beautifications go inte the "manual" file that won-t be overwritten by the codegenerator.

In the java/hybris world they use inheritance for the none-generated-code:

You have for example a class Customer with your "api-beautifications" that inherits from "GeneratedCustomer".

Comment: It's an interesting solution, but I fear it remains in the realm of a maintenance overhead (writing / updating wrapper classes for each change in the generated code). But thanks!